# How to convert this date in required format

Tags: java

I am reading rss feeds using DOM API .
As part of pubDate iamreciving date in this format

```
Sun, 01 Nov 2015 06:27:09 +0000
```

I need to convert date into this format

```
2015-11-01 06:27
```

This is what i tried

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
         String today = convertdate("Sun, 01 Nov 2015 06:27:09 +0000");
            System.out.println(today);
    }
    public static String convertdate(String recivieddate) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("E,dd MM yy HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = in.parse(recivieddate);

        SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        String newdate = out.format(date);

        return newdate.toString();
    }
}
```

But the exception i am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun, 01 Nov 2015 06:27:09 +0000"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at Test.convertdate(Test.java:13)
    at Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `E,dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss` to parse

Try with this

```
import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

public class test {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
             String today = convertdate("Sun, 01 Nov 2015 06:27:09 +0000");
                System.out.println(today);
        }
        public static String convertdate(String recivieddate) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("E,dd MMM yy HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = in.parse(recivieddate);

            SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            String newdate = out.format(date);

            return newdate.toString();
        }
    }
```

**output** 2015-11-01 06:27

Comment: @Kiran, if this answer solved your problem, you should probably accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ...

```
 package com.paytm.pg.common;

        import java.text.ParseException;
        import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
        import java.util.Date;


        public class Test {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
                 String today = convertdate("Sun, 01 Nov 2015 06:27:09 +0000");
                    System.out.println(today);
            }
            public static String convertdate(String recivieddate) throws ParseException {
                SimpleDateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = in.parse(recivieddate);

                SimpleDateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                String newdate = out.format(date);

                return newdate.toString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a library, you can parse the date without specifying a format.

```
import org.pojava.datetime.DateTime;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TimeZone utc=TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    String formatted=DateTime.parse("Sun, 01 Nov 2015 06:27:09 +0000")
      .toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", utc));
    // 2015-11-01 06:27
}
```